# Can I programmatically generate and show a bitmap using Blazor Client?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

Is there any way I can generate a bitmap at runtime calculating the RGBA value for each pixel and then show that bitmap on the UI in the context of using Blazor Client?

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far ?

Comment: There are image libraries such as ImageSharp (last time I tried SkiaSharp it didn't work in Blazor WebAssembly due to some dependency issues) that will work, but currently Blazor in WebAssembly is significantly slow for this sort of thing and best avoided. 

I would recommend offloading any processing intensive tasks to a remote api that returns the image to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ImageSharp, though it it is rather slow. Then just convert to base64 and use as `<img />` source.

Note that apparently there seems to be a limit during initialization (`OnInitialized/OnParametersSet/OnAfterRender`) and you won't be able to create more than 128x128x32, rendering pipeline will freeze. But if the generator code is triggered after the page has been generated, it seems to work fine with even large images. It is slow though.

**ImageGeneratorBase.razor.cs**

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using SixLabors.Primitives;
using SixLabors.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace StackOverflow.Sample1.Shared {
    public class ImageGeneratorBase : ComponentBase {
        [Parameter]
        public int Width { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public int Height { get; set; }

        protected string Image64 { get; set; }

        public void Generate() {
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Image img = new Image<Rgba32>(Width, Height))
                {
                    PathBuilder pathBuilder = new PathBuilder();
                    pathBuilder.SetOrigin(new PointF(0, 0));
                    pathBuilder.AddBezier(new PointF(Width / 5.0f, Height), new PointF(2 * Width / 5.0f, 0), new PointF(3 * Width / 5.0f, Height), new PointF(4 * Width / 5.0f, 0));
                    IPath path = pathBuilder.Build();

                    img.Mutate(ctx => ctx
                        .Fill(Color.Black)
                        .Draw(Color.White, 3, path)
                    );
                    img.SaveAsPng(outStream);

                }

                Image64 = "data:image/png;base64, " + Convert.ToBase64String(outStream.ToArray());
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageGenerator.razor**

```cs
@inherits ImageGeneratorBase
@if (Image64 != null) {
    <img src=@Image64 />
}
```

**Index.razor**

```html
@page "/"

<p>
    <Button @onclick=@(e => generator.Generate())>Generate image</Button>
</p>
<p>
    <ImageGenerator Width=256 Height=256 @ref=@generator />
</p>

@code {
    ImageGenerator generator;
}
```

Comment: Some notes regarding the size limitation: 
With any image larger than 128 X 128 the page hangs (I tried Chrome and Edge). The issue is not a size limitation for the base64 source for the image. I ported your code in a console app that generates an HTML file with a similar content. That HTML can be loaded in browsers even when it contains large images (2000 X 2000). When run via Blazor & WebAssembly the page hangs even if the line that sets Image64 Is commented out. The fact that the maximum size is 128 X 128 must mean something.

Comment: Whatever the reason for it is, I found that the limit is only enforced during initialization. If you trigger image generation after the component has already been rendered for the first time, it seems to work even with large images. I edited my answer to provide an example.